# Is this a good idea: PHP process for each user that logs on

Tags: php, ajax, process

I am developing a web application, which needs to spawn a process per user. This is done when they navigate to a certain page. I have an AJAX call that calls a PHP script (which then sits and reads data items from the database/session) and goes to sleep, like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
while($_SESSION['continue']) {
// Do some processing
session_write_close();
sleep(30);   
session_start();
}
exit();
```

When the user navigates away from the page the 'continue' session variable is set to false and the php process above ends.

The processing being carried out is not significant. Reads a few records from database and checks somethings.

Question: Is this a good idea? Will it cause any obvious memory issues when there are lots of users online?

Many thanks,
Arvy

Comment: A standard Apache child can only process ONE request at a time. If you allow (say) 100 children, then you can have at MOST 99 users on your site - 1 user actively loading SOME page, and 99 children running your do-not-very-much loop. And once that 100th child starts running your loop, you've effectively locked EVERYONE out of your site. Now the continue variable can never be changed, and your site is dead.

Comment: Of course, hopefully at some point the script will reach  max_execution_time and get killed by Apache, but in the meantime, nothing very much is going to be happening.

Comment: @MarcB I'll look into setting the children setting higher as well as checking the current number in order to prevent the lock. I have manually set the timeout limit, which is pretty high, but needed for what I wanted to accomplish. So like you said it would eventually kick out of it, but would take a while! Thanks for your comments.

Comment: it'd likely take a long time. time spent in sleep() doesn't count against execution time, and if your processing chunk is short enough, it could be MANY iterations before the limit's hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're ultimate goal is, but `sleep` is non-blocking and ideally that should be where the bottleneck of the script is.  You shouldn't have to worry about CPU if all other things are fast.

However, each request will add a process to the table and since the processes never (or rarely) exit, your process table will fill up and you will eventually not be able to serve any more requests -- thus this is not a good idea.

Instead what you may want to do is go through the processing on each request.  I would expect users to make requests about every 30 seconds.  Another possible alternative is to use a cron job that runs every minute and acts on logged in users, or to have some other daemon that you can signal when a user logs in that does the processing for logged in users on a schedule.

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills. Interesting points, I liked the idea of having on job loop through the logged on users and doing the processing. Will look into this a bit more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has helped me so much!! I can't believe I wasted so much time trying to setup a monitor for each individual user. I will now implement something like this: active_users table and a php script to go through the table and process the changes. Perfect! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not a good idea, for a number of reasons.

First of all, if you are running on Apache, which you most likely are, you are going to run out of Apache processes, because it uses one process per request. Your script is a request which will take a very long time to finish, and so with each user logged in there's less processes available, ultimately resulting in a complete lockdown following a gradually more noticeable slowdown.

It is also very easy to abuse this, in case an attacker finds out you are using this - a DoS / DDoS keeping sessions alive would be deadly to your website / server.

It might slow down the users' browsers, not a great deal, but it is a request that will never ever be processed completely, unless you are planning to keep outputting data to the client, which is not a good idea either. AJAX tends to use a greater amount of smaller pull requests, as they are less of a pain to control and they are not as demanding for the browsers.

If you are going with this, and I advise you not to, you need a `set_time_limit(0);` at the beginning of the script anyway, as your code would automatically be killed by PHP.

To suggest an alternative, have the AJAX request something of the browser periodically (e.g. 30 seconds as you wanted) - the PHP script gets called every 30 seconds and you can do your processing, taking minimal amount of processing time.

I assume this is for something like last user activity stat / who is online for your website. If you take a look at how websites like Facebook do this, you will see that the browser keeps sending 'pull' requests to a server, and in return, the server sends information like new notifications, messages, online user list, news feed entries, etc.

Comment: Good point about the DoS issue. I should have thought about that before! I have now made the process independent of the client. There is also only one process to go through the logged on users. Thanks for your insight.